# such empty alert with jsx / react alternatives

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, ecmascript-6, jsx

So I was thinking I found a great way to alert users that the array is empty and there's nothing to display but actually my technique is not well implemented and only works onFocus or page reload, I put the function on `componentDidMount()`

```
componentDidMount = () => {
this.setState({loading: true})
const { currentUser } = fire.auth();
    fire.database().ref(`/master/${currentUser.uid}/feed/sponsors/`)
    this.setState({
    sponsorsList:sponsorsList,
 }, () => {
    if (this.state.sponsorsList.length === 0)
        this.setState({loading: false, empty: true})
   });
 });
}
```

This works but such empty text in the view still appears after I push something to the array, how do I trigger that `.length` function ?

```
{this.state.empty ? <h6 class='mb-3'>Such empty!</h6> : null }
```

Please someone suggest a better alternative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to add `else` logic:

```
if (this.state.sponsorsList.length === 0) {
    this.setState({ loading: false, empty: true })
} else { // Here are the additions
    this.setState({ loading: false, empty: false })
}
```

Oh, then you can write:

```
{this.state.empty && <h6 class="mb-3">Such empty!</h6>}
```

Hope it helps :)